# android xml layout buttons error

Tags: android, xml, include

I've this problem. Because I couldn't see all content with scrollview, I divide the xml in two xml files, using `include`.
The problem is that the two button in the bottom of the screen are not below the cardview, but I've obtained this in image:

[image]

my xml code of the first file is this:

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1600dp"
    android:id="@+id/scr">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.plenitudesrls.aviocalc.MyAircrafts.AddAircraftFirstPartFragment">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1250dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/pleaseaircraftspeeds"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    tools:ignore="NotSibling" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/firstBorder"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
                    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/vso"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
                    android:id="@+id/vso"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/firstSub"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/firstBorder"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                    android:text="@string/stallspeedlanding" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="20sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/firstET"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/firstSub"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstBorder"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/firstBorder"
                    android:hint="@string/nullkt"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/fiveBorder"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
                    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/fourBorder"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourBorder"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourBorder"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fourBorder"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fourBorder" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/vy"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/vy"
                    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fiveBorder"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vx"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/vx" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/fiveSub"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="@string/bestrate"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/vy"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vy"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vy" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="20sp"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/fiveET"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:hint="@string/nullkt"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/fiveSub"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourET"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourET" />

                <include
                    layout="@layout/fragment_add_aircraft_four_part2"
                    android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"
                    android:layout_below ="@+id/fiveBorder"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"

                />



            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/card_view"
            android:divider="@drawable/button_divider"
            android:showDividers="middle"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/backColor"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@color/backColor"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/buttonDivider"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/button_divider" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Right"
                android:id="@+id/next"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/greenColor"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@color/greenColor" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

and this is the code of the second xml (I've cut some similar textview/edittext):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tenSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/landingref"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vref"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vref"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vref" />



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tenET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tenSub"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nineET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nineET" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/elevenET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/elevenSub"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/eightET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/eightET" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/elevenBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/elevenBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/elevenBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/elevenBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/elevenBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vne"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/elevenSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/elevenSub" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/twelveSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/neverexceedspeed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vne"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vne" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/twelveET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vne"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vne"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/elevenET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/elevenET" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#424242"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/twelveBorder" />


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vcruise"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/twelveBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/elevenSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/elevenSub" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/eightET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vfeten"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vfeten"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sevenET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sevenET" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/elevenBorder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/thirtET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/thirtBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vcruise"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vcruise"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/thirtET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirtBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/thirtSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/cruisingspeed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vcruise"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vcruise"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vcruise" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/thirtBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vapproach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vappr"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirtSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirtSub"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fourtSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/approachspeed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vappr"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vappr"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vappr" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/fourtET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vappr"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thirtET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/thirtET" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#BDBDBD"
        android:id="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourtBorder" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/separator"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/separator" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vle"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourtSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourtSub" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/fiftSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/maximumlandingearextended"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vle"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vle" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/fiftET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fiftSub"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourtET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourtET" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/sixtBorder"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_textview"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fiftBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fiftBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vlo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vlo"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sixtBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fiftSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fiftSub" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sixtSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/maximumlandingearoperating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vlo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vlo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vlo" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/sixtET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vlo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/vlo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fiftET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fiftET" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#BDBDBD"
        android:id="@+id/separatortwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sixtBorder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fourtBorder"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fourtBorder" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_colored"
        android:layout_below="@+id/separatortwo"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView10" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/va"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/va"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sixBorder"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/vref"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/vref" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="20sp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/sixET"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:hint="@string/nullkt"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/va"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/va"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/thirtBorder"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/thirtBorder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/sixSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/maneuveringspeed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sixET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/va"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/va" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nineSub"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="@string/maximumlandingearextended"
        android:layout_below="@+id/vfefull"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/vcruise"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/vcruise" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/vfefull"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vfefull"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nineBorder"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nineSub"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nineSub" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

what I need to change to make it good?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes on the `CardView` seems to be messing up your view. Change the attributes of the `CardView` as follows,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    ....

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Changes,

- Remove the hardcoded height and set it to `wrap_content`.
- Remove the `layout_centerVertical` attribute.

Comment: this with "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent" in linear layout solves my problem...thanks ;)